# Use value in other column in loop while

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have this query in SQL Server and I have a table Rezotel with column name Gun int type.

I want to replace the number 100 in 'WHILE @i - 100 <= 0' by the value in Gun column
Edit -The point is I want it to iterate over the same row N number of times where N equals the Gun value of that row, so  duplicate the insert of each row N number of times

```
DECLARE @TEST table (RecID int, D1 DATE)
DECLARE @i int = 0;
    WHILE @i - 100 <= 0
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i+1
        INSERT INTO @TEST
        SELECT RezOtel.RecID,RezOtel.CikisTarihi-@i AS D1 FROM RezOtel
    END
```

Comment: Feels like you want a Table-Valued Function

Comment: you need dynamic sql for that

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense on first read. Presumably you have more than 1 row in your `Rezotel` table. And safe to assume not all rows have the same value for the `Gun` column. What is the goal you want to achieve?...if I had to take a guess, you want it to iterate over the same row `N` number of times where `N` equals the `Gun` value of that row, so you can duplicate the insert of each row `N` number of times?

Comment: This looks to me like a join to a tally table or number range - far from clear though. Sample data and desired results are needed.

Comment: Yes the point is I want it to iterate over the same row N number of times where N equals the Gun value of that row, so duplicate the insert of each row N number of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments it appears something like the following might be what you're after (untested of course).

Using either a tally table (table of numbers) or a number series generated on the fly like below (SQLServer 2022 will support [GenerateSeries()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)), join this to your source table and limit the rows based on the row's value of `Gun`

```
with 
 l0 as (select 0 v from (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))v(v)), 
 l1 as (select 0 v from l0 a cross join l0 b),
 nums as (select n = Row_Number() over(order by @@Spid) from l1)

insert into @TEST (RecID, D1)
select r.RecID, DateAdd(day, -n, r.CikisTarihi) as D1 
from RezOtel r
join nums n on n.n <= r.Gun;
```

Comment: I like this approach. Note to OP this has a limit of `Gun` value being no greater than 100, if I read that right. But that can easily be increased by either adding more values to the first CTE or cross joining it to itself more times.